# How to show spaces from textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi I'm saving data in a text area on page 1 then showing it on page 2 in a div.  However if I write in the textarea

```
A

B

C

D
```

It shows it in the div (on page 2) as

```
A B C D
```

How do I maintain the line breaks?

Comment: Either convert `\n` to `<br />`, or use a `<pre>` (or similar styling for preserving whitespace)

Comment: You can use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: which script prints out the string in div on page 2 ? is it javascript or php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CSS property [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to accept `\n` as new lines.

```
div {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPy84/)**

Comment: why write this for all div's ?

Comment: The selector is arbitrary for the sake of the demo. OP can inherit for his implementation.

Comment: yea i guess the question is pretty ambiguous. Every web designing language was tagged

Comment: This works for me. However I used a style tag within a div to do this instead of applying to all divs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this function [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) and FYI Don't use `nl2br` when you save it to the database. Use it when you're displaying the text in HTML.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're using it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the below code:

```
function setVal() {
    var content = document.getElementById('test').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
}
```

**Explanation:** Basically, the need is to convert the `\n` characters to their equivalent HTML line breaks using `<br/>`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L66HE/)

Comment: Because it's extremely over complicating the problem.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst: Fair enough. I think you are referring to the usage of CSS `pre` right?

Comment: OP did tag as `javascript`, so I think this is an option.

Comment: Of course it's an option but OP stated the the content is output via PHP. Why in the world would you post process it in JavaScript?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst: Again I think you do make a fair point. But I also agree with the others who commented. Every language was tagged and hence the option in Javascript was provided. I don't think either your option or mine deserved a down-vote just for that reason. But then voting is your wish :)

Comment: OP's not interacting with anyone (expecting a magical answer); I voted to close as unclear. Magic is inside crystal balls; I don't have mine tonight.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Done the same just now.

Comment: @Harry OP's track record isn't hot.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `<pre>` tag which is used for preformatted texts like this on your second page.

An example of which would be this:

```
<?
  echo '<pre>'.$_POST['textarea'].'</pre>';
```

It preserves both spaces and linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$textarea = strip_tags($_POST['textarea']);
echo '<textarea>'.nl2br($textarea).'</textarea>';
```

`nl2br` = new line to `<br>`, so it'll insert `<br><br>` for every carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

### You should use nl2br when displaying the value in div

#### [Online Demo](http://goo.gl/EOwKQB)

Here is the code so that you can run it check.

```
<form>
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message here"><?=$_REQUEST['message']?></textarea><br>
    <button name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<h2>Your message will display here</h2>
<div><?=nl2br($_REQUEST['message'])?></div>

<h3>Always remember that don't store nl2br value in database.</h3>
```